# How to build a dynamic query string to execute on a spark-sql 2.3.1 dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax, databricks

I have a requirement to get the where condition passed by user as program arguments. Based on the where condition i need to query the source data base.

I am using spark-sql.2.3.1
How to construct and pass/executive dynamically build query?

Sample query:

```
select ProductId, COUNT(*) AS ProductSaleCount
 from productsale
 where to_date(Date) >= "2015-12-17"
 and to_date(Date) <= "2015-12-31"
 group by ProductId
```

Comment: @Alex ott , sir how are you editing it so neatly when i tried it is not in proper format... where/how can I format it like you did ?

Comment: just ident the code with 4 spaces, or select the code and press `{}` icon... Here is instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do in your scenario is create a query string which would go something like:

```
val query = "select ProductId, COUNT(*) AS ProductSaleCount from productsale where to_date(Date) >= "+ fromDate +" and to_date(Date) <= " + toDate + " group by ProductId"
```

the fromDate and toDate, you would get from your arguments, perhaps.

To use this, however is a different issue and it depends on your database

For hive you can simply register your spark session with enableHiveSupport

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("My App").enableHiveSupport().config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation).getOrCreate()

val data = spark.sqlContext.sql(query)
```

If the data is in a dataframe and you want to query that, you would have to create a view and then run your query on that

```
finalDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("productsale")

val data = spark.sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i try to run after enableHaveSupport() it is giving error  " Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106) "

Comment: i am still getting error https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21297036